# Is it possible to set a custom notification sound instead of default with cordova-plugin-geofence

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, localnotification

My requirement is to set a custom notification alert tone in ionic 3 but the plugin documentation does not provide sound parameter in notification object while Localnotification plugin provies.

I have tried to do it using audio plugin inside onTransitionReceived() method.Now the audio is playing while app is in foreground but not working while the app is in background?

Is there any solution to do it??